# How to first download audio files from URLs and then play all - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, download, playback

I have got multiple audio files on server.

I want to download all audio files first, and then when all are downloaded, i need to play them one after another.

What will be the best approach to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you download those files like you would download any regular file?

Comment: @Sha : Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @AymenBRomdhane No bro :( I ended up streaming them using StreamingKit by TumTumTum on Github